# Hierarchical cluster analysis with mixed data

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, binary-data, hierarchical-clustering, mixed-type-data

I have a dataset consisting of 134 observations and four variables. The dataset consists of answers to a questionnaire. I want to perform a hierarchical cluster analysis on the variables in the dataset, but as they are all measured differently I am unsure about how to proceed.

Two of my variables are categorical, ranging from 1-3, with no order between them. The two other variables are both binary variables, with values 0 and 1 (no/yes). I have tried using Gowers distance for mixed measure data, but the resulting clusters do not make sense conceptually. I have also tried making all the variables into binary variables. This way I have three variables for each of the initial categorical variables, where each variable is given the value 1 if it corresponds to one of the categories in the original variable. I then run these variables in a cluster analysis with averagelinkage and the dice distance measure for binary data. This approach gives me more meaningful clusters than Gower, and the clusters are well separated and make sense conceptually given the data I have. However, I am unsure whether this approach can be used and I would appreciate any feedback as the information I have read online and on different forums is conflicting and confusing.